# Having trouble converting milliseconds to a nicely formatted hours, minutes, and seconds string

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, time, string-formatting, milliseconds

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I want to take a time in milliseconds (a duration, not a UTC time) and convert it into hours, minutes and seconds.  I’m trying this

```
    Time.at(time_in_ms).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

but this doesn’t seem to be working.  For instance, in my POstGresql database, I have this amount of milliseconds

```
3601000
```

and the above is producing

```
16:16:40
```

even though it should produce something like “1:00:01” (one hour and one second).  What is the proper way to convert time in milliseconds to a nicely formatted hours, minutes, and seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Time.at()` expects a time in **seconds** *after* a certain epoch - 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC - so your code needs to divide the `ms` figure by 1000 first:

```
Time.at(time_in_ms/1000).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

**EDIT:** I just rechecked the Ruby docs: the below rider is *incorrect*! The passed-in number of seconds is assumed to be in UTC, so `at()` does the calculation THEN factors in the UTC offset. The above `.utc` undoes that factoring, and is required.

---

Of course, the problem with that code then becomes your current time zone. Say you're at UTC-5 (New York time): `Time.at(3601000/1000)` becomes `"01:00:01"` local time. Converting it to UTC would subtract five hours from the hour figure, making it `"20:00:01"`. So remove your `.utc` conversion too:

```
Time.at(time_in_ms/1000).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your second expression but that produced the result "20:00:01" for the "3601000" time in milliseconds.  It should ahve produced "1:00:01", no?

Comment: What timezone are you in? Did you try my first expression?

Comment: The expression I have, "3601000," is a duration, not a time since 1970 or whatever that phrase is.  I woudl like to write a formatting expression taht will output the same number, "1:00:01" no matter what time zone I'm in since I'm not referring to clock time, per se.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Absolutely! The issue is, if you don't want to code the time mess yourself (which you could), but wanted to use the features provided for you, then you have to work with their constraints. A long as you don't print the month or the year, and don't do a duration of more than 31 days, then duration and time-since-1-Jan-1970 are the same. The timezone nonsense is fixed with `.utc`

Comment: Ah, I hear what you're saying.  Yup the first expression works perfectly.  Thanks for the extra explanation.